# Unable to Upload Image to Server ios

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, file-upload, image-uploading

Hello I am trying to upload Image From my IOS device to server.

And Here Is my code to upload the Image

```
- (IBAction)btnUpload:(id)sender {

    if (self.imageViewGallery.image == nil) {
        UIAlertView *ErrorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Wait"
                                                             message:@"Please Select An Image To Upload." delegate:nil
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                   otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [ErrorAlert show];
        NSLog(@"error");
    }
    else{
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageViewGallery.image, 90);
    NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/ColorPicker/api.upload.php";


    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
        NSString *imgName = LIbraryImage;
        NSLog(@"image name : %@",imgName);

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"files\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", imgName]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSLog(@"setRequest : %@", request);


    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"returnstring is : %@",returnString);
    }
```

Now here is my server side code. It is a bit long.

```
  <?php

$Image = $_FILES['files']['name'];
    print_r($_FILES);
foreach ($Image as $f => $name) {

    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $temp = explode(".", $name);
    $extension = end($temp);

    if ((($_FILES['files']['type'][$f] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$f] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$f] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES['files']['type'][$f] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES['files']['size'][$f] < 2000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {
        if ($_FILES['files']['error'][$f] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES['files']['error'][$f] . "<br>";
        } else {

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $name)) {

            } else {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$f], 'upload/' . uniqid() . "_" . $name);
            }
        }
    } else {
        $error = "Invalid file";
    }

}
?>
```

Now what happen every time I try to upload got this warning

```
<b>Warning</b>:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in <b>/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ColorPicker/uploadAction.php</b> on line <b>5</b><br />
```

Comment: Which else block is running in your PHP?  The "No POST" one or the "error" one?

Comment: NO POST all the time...

Comment: What's the output from the `print_r($_FILES)`?

Comment: Please post the output of `print_r($_FILES)`.

Comment: ye sir it is returning following array
 Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => iphone.jpg
            [type] => application/octet-stream
            [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php4VsKOv
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 13484
        )

)

Comment: well these guys aren't allowing to make any changes to php web service they said to change to ios code and I think the ios code is perfect isn't it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you upload image data as multipart, it end up in [`$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php).  Since PHP 4.3.0, `$_REQUEST` no longer contains any information about files uploaded in this manner.

The rest of your code is based around the idea of the image not being uploaded as multipart but instead being uploaded as a base-64 string in a standard form.  Instead of writing base 64 data to a file, you will simply need to get the information about the file from `$_FILES` and move it to your target directory with [`move_uploaded_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php).

Comment: Yep. Validate that the file was uploaded with `print_r($_FILES)`, then rewrite the PHP.

Comment: Sir I have done some changes could you please help me with that.

Answer (score 2):

From the comments, that `print_r` is returning:

```
Array ( 
    [files] => Array ( 
        [name] => iphone.jpg 
        [type] => application/octet-stream 
        [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/php4VsKOv 
        [error] => 0 
        [size] => 13484 
    )
)
```

Meanwhile, your code is doing this:

```
$Image = $_FILES['files']['name'];
print_r($_FILES);
foreach ($Image as $f => $name) {
```

You're treating `$_FILES['files']['name']` as if it's an array, when it isn't.  That's why PHP says "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

Please note that it *can* become an array if multiple files are uploaded with the same form element name.  This is by far *the* most infuriating thing about `$_FILES`.

Your uploading code does *not* attempt to use the PHP syntax needed to upload multiple files at once, so your PHP code does *not* need to worry about the content of the inner array being arrays themselves.  You can eliminate the `foreach` loop and all references to the `[$f]` index.