# how to upload image to server in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-upload, image-uploading

I want to upload one image to server using http post method.
the requirement is like in the body data should be attached as byte stream.

I converted image to `NSData` and attached that data to body of `NSUrlrequest`.
but i am getting **404** in status code of response.

```
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:UIImageData]];

[request setHTTPBody:body];
```

but i am getting **404 error** in status code.

is byte stream is same as `NSData` ?

if not then how to send byte stream data to server using `NSURLConnection` ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show a lot more of the code please

Comment: Your error is more than likely due to your URL being incorrect, but you should be Base64 encoding your image as the body.

Comment: Please check your URL and refer to this answer to check your code against it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564833/ios-upload-image-and-text-using-http-post

Comment: please add more code and go through this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20869848/unable-to-upload-image-to-server-ios

Answer (score 0):

What about the `URL` you're using to send the image to?

A 404 error code translates to  `Not Found` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404), so the first step should be making sure yore using a valid `URL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the upload that way:

```
NSData *yourData = //load your data here;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UPLOAD_URL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", UPLOAD_FILE, UPLOAD_FILE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:yourData]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    [connection start];
```